# Is it OK to use a public variable in C# if it is readonly?

Tags: c#, properties

Is there some internal difference between the C# syntactic sugar way of making properties:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

and just making public variables like this:

```
public string LastName;
```

I assume the first way is preferred and the second to be avoided. However, I often see this type of readonly property being used which is a form of the second type above:

```
public readonly string InternalCode;
```

Is this a best-practice way to create readonly property?

```
using System;

namespace TestProps
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.FirstName = "Jim";
            customer.LastName = "Smith";
            customer.Show();
        }
    }

    class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; } //prefered
        public string LastName; //avoid
        public readonly string InternalCode; //???

        public Customer()
        {
            InternalCode = "234729834723984";
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1} ({2})", LastName, FirstName, InternalCode);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since he didn't answer (yet) and no one else referenced this yet: There is a great article on this topic by Jon Skeet amending his book *C# in depth* (give credits to Jon):

> [**Why Properties Matter**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx)

Comment: that article was a two pages directly addressing my question, thanks! I understand from it that Jon would not even approve of "public readonly bool IsValid;" unless, as he mentions at the end, it is in a nested class

Comment: For those of us just looking for an answer and not a lengthy article, could you add a spoiler alert here and give us the yes or no answer?

Comment: The Skeet article actually makes a couple of exceptions, one of which could be applied to this question. According to the article, "I'll make a small exception for static readonly fields such as string.Empty". This question could have been modified and by moving the assignment from the constructor onto the same line would be public static readonly string InternalCode = "234729834723984";  As such, it would be a "static readonly field" just like Skeet described.

Answer (score 4):

Using a property provides an interface which is more resistant to change in the future. Let's say some time in the future, a decision is made to add a prefix to the internal code.

Using a public readonly variable exposes your internal structure and you will have a hard time adding the prefix to every line you used the internal variable of the class.

Using a Property, you can just write the following

```
public string InternalCode { 
    get { return _prefix + _internalCode; } 
}
```

and you're done!

Comment: This short exchange highlights exactly the question I came here looking for. Why isn't the "readonly" flag a more useful flag? By removing "readonly", you signal to all callers that they cannot cache this value... they need to re-get it every time in case it has changed. You can document that it will never change, but if you document that, then you can't take advantage of the flexibility of the property that is touted above -- making it changeable would violate the property's contract. So the original question is unanswered: Why wouldn't you prefer a readonly field over a get-only property?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it's ok to expose public fields (especially if they're readonly or const). Having said that, I'd say that in the example you're presenting, I'd probably go with properties since they'll give you 2 advantages (over fields): 1) better encapsulation and may let you adapt your code in the future and 2) if you're doing data binding, then you do need the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. it is OK to have a public readonly variables (it is just that they can be initialized at the time of definition or constructor).

e.g. Decimal.MaxValue

Having public readonly property is good, if the backing value changes (other than what it was initialized with).

e.g. Environment.TickCount

I thought that Environment.NewLine will be a public readonly variable. Well, it is a public property (get only) and the reason could be to maintain compatibility across different platform.

Comment: What is wrong with this? Please post the reason when down-voting. It will help me realize my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: No vote from me, but actually Decimal.MaxValue is a const and not an instance field (Read the article by Jon Skeet linked in my answer for reasons not to expose fields)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: public **const** is ok, public readonly not necessarily, public get without set not neccessarily.
Objects that cannot be changed without being assigned can be ok. Reference types are dangerous as you can still change their values, even if you cannot change the reference itself.

The problem with the readonly keyword is that it does not mean what you'd understand as logically readonly/immutable. It means more like "can only be assigned in constructor". References cannot be changed, but its values can. There is no "real" readonly keyword provided by c#, unfortunately. See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/

Properties cannot have the readonly keyword (https://titombo.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/using-the-c-modifiers/). 
As others noted, you can use a property and only define get and no set, though you cannot set that property in the constructor. Using a private set, you can set the property from *annywhere* in the class, *not* only in the constructor. The readonly field would be a little more restrictive.